# Vercel + Reactjs & Vite Returning 404 on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, vite, vercel

So i have a code base that i built using React, TailwindCSS, and Vite using react router as the routing.

For some reason when built going to the home page and the rest of the pages work perfect, but once i refresh, i am given a 404 error.

i have checked my vercel.json file. i have tried other solutions that have been posted on here and im not sure where im going wrong. I have tried adding this file in the root of my folder (where it currently is) and also inside my src folder as i seen some examples with that as well.

I have tried changing

```json
routes: [
{ 
 "src" :  //here
 }
 ]
```

per examples i have seen but to luck!

let me know what i need to do or if youd like to see any other files, but the src code is available here

https://github.com/InsurTech-Groups/home-form-english

Thanks!

#### Additional information

vercel.json

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "package.json",
      "use": "@vercel/node",
      "config": {
        "maxLambdaSize": "75mb"
      }
    },
    {
      "src": "index.html",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": {
        "distDir": "dist",
        "command": "npm run build",
        "env": {
          "NODE_ENV": "production"
        },
        "output": {
          "clean": true
        },
        "postbuild": {
          "command": "npm run postbuild",
          "env": {
            "BUILD_DIR": "$VERCEL_BUILD_OUTPUT_DIR"
          }
        },
        "files": [
          "dist/**/*",
          "public/**/*",
          "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "!**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": [{ "src": "/[^.]+", "dest": "/", "status": 200 }],
      "dest": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

Links
GithubURL: https://github.com/InsurTech-Groups/home-form-english
Live Vercel Site: https://home-form-english.vercel.app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like the issue fixed when i deleted everything in the vercel.json and just had this

```json
{
  "rewrites": [{ 
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "/" }]
}
```

Comment: meaning any path mentioned in source `"/(.*)"` will rewrite requests to `"/"` destination...

source : vercel docs (https://vercel.com/docs/projects/project-configuration#rewrites)

Comment: I can't find any vercel.json. Should I add it manually to the root of my project?

Answer (score 0):

Also, the solution can be that in the vercel.json file add this part for routes:

```
{
  // ...
  "routes": [
    // ...
    { "handle": "filesystem" }
  ]
}
```